# Напоминания телеграм бота в одно время каждый день

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю бота с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI. Нужно сделать следующее: пользователю разово предлагается ввести время, в которое он согласен получать уведомления(например, 11:30), а бот ежедневно присылает сообщения в это время. Время только московское, без учета часовых поясов.
С помощью какой библиотеки это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Через любую, что умеет работать с телеграммом. Делал для тренировки бота для уведомлений типа "напомни через 1 час", вам нужно по аналогии сделать: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c191ce08fbdeb29377639184579e392057945154/telegram_bot_examples/reminder/main.py#L25 Т.е. хранить где-то, например, в базе данных инфу о времени уведомления и `chat_id`, и делать рассылку, когда время придет. Рассылку можно сделать в цикле отдельным скриптом или отдельным потоком

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку datatime. Создайте функцию `bot.register_next_step_handler` и запишите в переменные часы и минуты. Потом можно организовать цикл, который будет сравнивать совпадает ли указанное время с текущим. Если да, то с помощью id отсылаете пользователю нужное сообщение.